# How to fix responsive CSS on Bootstrap 3?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, responsive-design

I just started using Bootstrap 3 and I have problem with responsive view. Everything works great but small screen.

Side bar extends to whole page no matter what is inside.

Here is example I just wrote. http://www.bootply.com/HEGU2LjD2J (see mobile view)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find

`<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>`

and replace it with

`<div class="clearfix visible-xs visible-sm"></div>`

Comment: Thank you ... that did the trick. I checked in code and found out the difference I did not notices :/ sm and xs ...